# Adobe Flex/AIR acceptDragDrop not working

Tags: apache-flex, air

I want to drop things in an HTMl component from inside and outside the AIR application.
Droping from outside the application works fine but I can't drop stuf from a List, calling the acceptDragDrop has no visual effect and no functionality effect the drop event is not dispatched. I tried using only the DragManager, then only the NativeDragManager but the same effect.  I do not understand what is missing ,why that method is not accepting the drop.

I have some sample code(there are some portions with experiments commented out)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
        private function get testData():ArrayCollection{
            var a:ArrayCollection=new ArrayCollection;
            var arr:Array=[{label:"T1"},{label:"T2"},{label:"T3"}];
            a.source=arr;
            return a;
        }

        protected function htmlSummary_dragDropHandler(event:DragEvent):void
        {
            if(event.dragInitiator is List){
                var tree:List=event.dragInitiator as List;
                var item:*=tree.selectedItem;
                trace(item);

            }
            trace("DRAG dROP");
        }
        private var dragEvent:DragEvent;
        protected function htmlSummary_dragEnterHandler(event:DragEvent):void
        {
            this.dragEvent=event;
            trace("DRAG ENTER");
        }

        protected function windowedapplication1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            this.htmlSummary.htmlLoader.addEventListener(NativeDragEvent.NATIVE_DRAG_ENTER,htmlSummary_nativeDragEnterHandler,true,0,true);
            this.htmlSummary.htmlLoader.addEventListener(NativeDragEvent.NATIVE_DRAG_DROP,htmlSummary_nativeDragDropHandler);

        }

        protected function htmlSummary_dragCompleteHandler(event:DragEvent):void
        {
            this.dragEvent=null;
            trace("DRAG COMPLETE");
        }

        protected function htmlSummary_dragExitHandler(event:DragEvent):void
        {
            this.dragEvent=null;
            trace("drag exit");
        }

        protected function htmlSummary_nativeDragEnterHandler(event:NativeDragEvent):void
        {
        //  if(dragEvent)
            NativeDragManager.acceptDragDrop(InteractiveObject(event.currentTarget));
            trace("native drag enter");
        }

        protected function htmlSummary_nativeDragDropHandler(event:NativeDragEvent):void
        {
            if(dragEvent){
                var item:*;
                if(dragEvent.currentTarget is List){
                    item=List(dragEvent.currentTarget).selectedItem;
                    if(item)
                        Alert.show(item.label);
                }
            }
            trace("native drag drop");
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<s:List width="130" height="100%" dataProvider="{testData}" dragEnabled="true"/>
<mx:HTML id="htmlSummary" location="http://google.com" width="100%" height="100%" 
        />
         <!--
nativeDragEnter="htmlSummary_nativeDragEnterHandler(event)"
nativeDragDrop="htmlSummary_nativeDragDropHandler(event)"
         dragComplete="htmlSummary_dragCompleteHandler(event)"
         dragDrop="htmlSummary_dragDropHandler(event)"  
        dragEnter="htmlSummary_dragEnterHandler(event)"
        dragExit="htmlSummary_dragExitHandler(event)"
        -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try separating the two dragDrops. Something that works for me adapted to your code (haven't tested, but just changed the function names etc.)

```
protected function htmlSummary_dragOverHandler(event:DragEvent):void
{ 

       if(event.dragSource.hasFormat('treeItems')){
                    DragManager.showFeedback(DragManager.COPY); //dropped from list             
                    DragManager.acceptDragDrop(InteractiveObject(event.currentTarget));
            }               
            else if(event.dragSource.hasFormat('air:file list')){ //dropped from fileSystem
                DragManager.showFeedback(DragManager.COPY);
                NativeDragManager.acceptDragDrop(InteractiveObject(event.currentTarget));
            }
       }

}

    protected function htmlSummary_dragDropHandler(event:DragEvent):void
    {
        if(event.dragSource.hasFormat('treeItems')){                    
           var item:* = event.dragSource.dataForFormat("treeItems")[0];
        } else if (event.dragSource.hasFormat('air:file list')){
            var item:* = event.dragSource.dataForFormat("air:file list")[0];
        }

    }
```

The event's listened there are just the regular DragEnter and DragOver instead of NativeDrag.

Comment: Hi,thx for your time, the code is nto working, as I said the accepotDragDrop is not working, also when debugging the DragManager acceptDragDrop we can see that it uses the NativeDraqgDrop manager the problem is that this one is not open source and I can't see what is happening there. I would apreciate if you could create a test air app and use my code  and just drag from the list on the html and see if you can get the DROP event fireing.